# Rijndael-256 encryption - Padding on end of decrypted string

Tags: php, mcrypt

So, I'm trying to decrypt Rijndael-256 using mcrypt, that's all good. 
However, there is padding on the very end of the string to make it exactly 32-bytes long.
Any idea why? Here's what it outputs.

```
array (size=9)
  'cryptedText' => string 'O¿{žû¦ê§Þøµ; *¬rÄÅÏ§„•T' (length=32)
  'IV' => string 'ÄêKG£ED^°“F¨ŠêFx)\e_¶üŠèJÂ|' (length=32)
  'title' => string 'Untitled' (length=8)
  'deleteKey' => string 'ff349d33af4cff27143f66680586121e3c17d1f81aee42c7beb645684ca95558447f0eba757c7ecc785ea39633cfad5a6144fd5ea5028ca9c342e15291d7fd60' (length=128)
  'date' => string '1356827615' (length=10)
  'uid' => string '0' (length=1)
  'urlID' => string '2' (length=1)
  'id' => string '2' (length=1)
  'decryptedText' => string 'hello woaaaaaaaaarld������������' (length=32)
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^ This
```

If I add more than 32 characters, it pads to 64, etc...

Here's how I'm decrypting it:

```
        $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');

        if (mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $result_set['IV']) != -1) {
            $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cipher, $result_set['cryptedText']);
            mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
            mcrypt_module_close($cipher);
            $result_set['decryptedText'] = $decrypted;
        }
```

The Rijndael-256 encrypted data is being stored in my database on LONGBLOB (binary) data type, aswell as the IV.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

> **data**
>
> The data that will be encrypted with the given cipher and mode.
>   **If the size of the data is not n * blocksize, the data will be padded
>   with '\0'**.
>
> The returned crypttext can be larger than the size of the data that
>   was given by data.

Answer (score 0):

base64_encoding my data before encrypting it solved this problem. Yay!

Comment: I'm no crypto-expert but I'm pretty sure this weakens your encryption considerably because your input-data is now in a very predictable format. Why not simply strip the null bytes, or add an integer that indicates the input-data length?

Comment: Why would it weaken the encryption?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I don't see why this makes the data "in a predictable format". Binary is rather the same thing logically, but nobody complains of it being in a predictable format.

Comment: Because you are left with only 64 bits of entropy on your input string, rather than a theoretical 2^32.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen What are you talking about?